# img styling is changing the way emojis are displayed

Tags: css, styling, emoji

I have a GatsbyJS website that uses NetlifyCMS. I restyled the images on my website to be centered. The issue i've found now is that all the emojis in the blog posts are now also in a new line and centered in the posts and it doesn't look good at all.

Is there anyway to style the img and emojis seperately? I am aware that emojis show up on the markdown file as images.

I have attached images of how the emojis look in the blog posts, the markdown file and the styling file.

Any solutions would be appreciated <3

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: add code instead of images, if you add the image it's hard for other developers to copy your code and edit it

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are using images.

In markdown the syntax

```markdown
![x](y)
```

will be rendered to html as

```html
<img src='y' alt='x'>
```

So, the solution is either using plain emoji as @ando-andriamalala suggested.

Or, if you really need to use image (I'm guessing for display consistency?), you can, assuming you only use this domain for your emoji needs:

```css
.Content img[src*="https://static.xx.fbcdn.net"] {
 ...
}
```

see [MDN CSS: Attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) for details

Answer (score -1):

Try to use copy and past emoji instead of image 
here a link https://getemoji.com/